# python subprocess 'ssh' returns no such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, azure-functions

When I run this subprocess locally, it works, however, when I deploy it in an azure function, it returns

(2, 'No such file or directory')

```
subprocess.run(['ssh', f'{user}@{host}', cmd],
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    check=True)
```

Error stack from azure:

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.AxesSearchApi Result: Failure
Exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ssh'
Stack:   File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 347, in _handle__invocation_request
    call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 511, in __run_sync_func
    return func(**params)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/AxesSearchApi/__init__.py", line 29, in main
    sshProcess = subprocess.run(["ssh", f'{user}@{host}', cmd],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
```

Comment: It probably can't find the `ssh` command...

Comment: It may be unable to find a local ssh or maybe you are seeing an error from remote host that it can't find `cmd`.  You could run `[`which`, `ssh`]` to see about the former. And maybe  `['ssh', f'{user}@{host}', 'which', cmd]` for the latter.  Was there a larger message that you trimmed up for us? It would be nice to see if this was a local python exception or something from the remote.

Comment: I only managed to catch that exception from python, azure did return another stack, but unrelated. i am going to add more logging

Answer (score 2):

the azure functions workers are intentionally slim, usually omitting any non-essential tools from the image they deploy on

it looks like the python 3 image does not contain an `ssh` binary

you can probably build a custom docker-based image instead of using the prebuilt images and install `ssh` into that